# Next.js failed to get redirect response TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I have this function in Next.js 13:

```js
async function createTodo(data: FormData) {
  "use server";
  const title = data.get("title")?.valueOf();
  if (typeof title !== "string" || title.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Invalid title");
  }

  await prisma.todo.create({ data: { title: title, complete: false } });
  redirect("/");
}
```

everything works perfectly until I place the **redirect("/");**
It shows me the following error:

```
prisma:query SELECT 1
prisma:query BEGIN
prisma:query INSERT INTO `main`.`Todo` (`id`, `title`, `complete`, `cleatedAt`, `updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING `id` AS `id`
prisma:query SELECT `main`.`Todo`.`id`, `main`.`Todo`.`title`, `main`.`Todo`.`complete`, `main`.`Todo`.`cleatedAt`, `main`.`Todo`.`updatedAt` FROM `main`.`Todo` WHERE `main`.`Todo`.`id` = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
prisma:query COMMIT
failed to get redirect response TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (/home/jorge/next-13-todo-list/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:26669) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at write (/home/jorge/next-13-todo-list/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:67105)
      at _resume (/home/jorge/next-13-todo-list/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:66726)
      at resume (/home/jorge/next-13-todo-list/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:65413)
      at connect (/home/jorge/next-13-todo-list/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:65301) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
```

What's going on?
Despite the error shown in the server console, the application remains alive and functional.
However, when returning to the / route, the result is not refreshed, any suggestions?.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is it server actions enabled on nextjsConfig ?

module.exports = {
experimental: {
serverActions: true,
},
};

Comment: Yes, this is the next.config.js file content:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: const title = data.get("title")?.valueOf();
  if (typeof title !== "string" || title.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Invalid title");
  }

  await prisma.todo.create({ data: { title: title, complete: false } });
Try to put this code in a separate file  the import it in your action

Comment: The changes made have the same effect  

Comment: I just discovered that this error occurs with next.js v13.4.12, if next.js v13.4.1 version is applied it works perfectly. I guess there must be a bug. This is not a solution but can help.

Answer (score 0):

The Vercel team has this bug under control in the 13.4.13-canary.11 version.

Let's wait for the upcoming stable version.

Do you what more info?, check my ticket:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53392